Time complexity of a BFS of a graph
I am unable to comprehend how the time complexity of the BFS of a graph is O(v+2E),
where V is the number of vertices and E being the number of edges.
/**
 * @param {number} V
 * @param {number[][]} adj
 * @returns {number[]}
*/
class Solution {
    // Function to return Breadth First Traversal of given graph.
    bfsOfGraph(V, adj) {
        const queue=new Queue();
        
        const visited=Array.from({length:V},()=>false);
        const ans=[];
        
        queue.add(0);
        visited[0]=true;

        
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            const el=queue.remove();
            ans.push(el);
            
            for(const v of adj[el]){
                if(!visited[v]){
                    queue.add(v);
                    visited[v]=true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
}


class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.arr = [];
        this.start = 0;
        this.end = -1;
    }


    add(el) {
        this.arr.push(el);
        this.end++;
    }


    remove() {
        if (this.isEmpty())
            return;

        let el = this.arr[this.start];
        this.start++;

        return el;
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return this.start > this.end;
    }

    get length() {
        return this.end - this.start < 0 ? 0 : this.end - this.start + 1;
    }
}

In the above javascript implementation of the BFS of a graph, since the queue only holds the
vertices that haven't been visited which makes the outer loop run for exactly V times and for each
vertex, we check if it's neigbouring nodes have been visited by looking at the visited array, which in
itself is an O(1) operation. So, technically for each vertex we make O(1) operations equal to the degree
of that vertex. So, why isn't the TC of the algorithm equal to O(V*avg. degree of a graph).
I tried everything but still don't have a clue. I checked a similar question on stack overflow but it didn't help.
Can someone explain me why it's O(V+E) instead of O(V*avg. degree of graph).

O(+) is (almost) the same thing as O() where  is the average degree. O() is not entirely correct when the graph is not connected. Take the extreme example where the graph has no edges, then  is 0, but obviously you still need to visit every node to find out it has no neighbors, so actually we should say O(+). With that correction they are equivalent:
As every edge connects two vertices, every edge adds one to the degree of two vertices, making the sum of the degrees equal to 2, giving us an average  = 2/.
If we substitute that in O(+) we get O(+2/) = O(+2) = O(+). Note that the factor 2 is irrelevant for big O notation and can be replaced with factor 1.

Thank you so much for the explanation.
But if we only talk about connected graphs only, wouldn't the time complexity be O(v*d) then.

Yes, but then it is also "only" O(E), as for connected graphs O(V+E) = O(E). The reason to specify O(V+E) is exactly to cover also for non-connected graphs.

Does that answer your question?

The reason it comes out to be O(V + 2E) is because there are O(1) operations that we do for each node like checking if the node is visited or not and marking the nodes as visited. So such O(1) operations are done for each node and that adds to the total time complexity. Thus, it's O(V+2E) and not just O(2E) or O(E).

It seems you miss the point that O(+2) is the same as O(+) -- look at the rules for big O notation I linked to in my answer, at Wikipedia: the factor 2 is irrelevant. And when we only look at connected graphs, then ≥−1, and so then  becomes irrelevant with respect to , making O(+) = O().

I mean yeah the constant here is irrelevant but i was just trying to paint a picture of what the exact TC would look like and yes, for connected graphs, it would be O(E) only but if we had to go down a common route for connected as well as disconnected graphs, i would say it to be O(V+E)

Yes. Which is what I had answered from the outset.  But then you came back to me in a comment asking 'if we only ask about connected graphs'... to which I replied in the comments that followed.

Thanks trincot for your help. Maybe i didn't understand it that well at that point.

The average degree of the graph is 2E/V, since each edge is counted for 2 vertices and you take the average. Therefore, V*avg.degree simplifies to 2E.
so what you are saying is that BFS is O(2E)=O(E) however, in a connected graph (and BFS is for them only) There isn't really any difference between O(V+E) and O(E) since V<E
